# Xcode produces an SSL error when attempting to upload app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, upload, app-store-connect

So I just upgraded my MacBook to Lion and setup all my prov profiles and Xcode 4.2.1. I followed the instructions here: http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442 to upload my app to the App Store. I have iTunes Connect all ready for my app update - it says waiting for upload. When I try with organizer to validate or submit my archive, it says `an SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made`. Has anybody ever seen this error before? I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: Sorry not that I know of. For me the problem went away after I tried uploading from my friends house.

Comment: If you changed connections, you may have a proxy or some other intermediary that is self-signing things.

Comment: hi im having this problem, but not related to internet connection. only apps that i implement admob mediation sdks are having this problem upon validation. im investigating this atm, but i believe it has something to do with files permissions settings. i'll write an answer if i find a solution later.

Comment: interesting I am also using admob in my app.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same error message and I tried using Application Loader, double checking password and account information, logging in via Safari, quitting Safari, etc.  What eventually worked for me was simply restarting my computer.

Very frustrating, but hopefully this helps someone else save 15 minutes of time.

Comment: thanks I actually got it to work by using going to my friends house and using his internet connection.

Comment: Logging out of Developer Console and back in again, also going to the "iOS Provisioning Profiles" page, worked for me. Xcode 5.

Comment: I had the same issue about 8 hours ago even after trying restarting Mac. I then gave up and try again now and it works. Could be because some issue in Apple.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have to leave my office and go to Starbucks to upload because my office's internet just doesn't seem to play well with Apple. Additionally, I had to restart my computer at Starbucks one time.

Answer (score 28):

Restarting Xcode worked for me. Hooray!

When this didn't work, restarting my computer worked. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

Try turning Wifi off and on again. This should get you a new internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

if you not getting after restart, upload after 24 hours, i succeded

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error several times. During the submission I was closing some of the applications that was opened namely ms word and photoshop and suddenly xcode was able to upload the release.

Answer (score 1):

This is now happening for me in Xcode6.4. There have been a number of SSL bugs and fixes lately and my guess is that they deprecated the encryption method used by Xcode6?

Fortunately the workaround was to use XCode7 to submit a build from XCode6 and everything seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my machine fixed the problem...until I tried to submit another app.  The second time, I just restarted XCode and, even though it took way longer than usual to upload, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem ended up being I was using a VPN. Turned it off and it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

flushing DNS worked for me: http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/20/flush-dns-cache-mac-os-x/

before that I also tried restarting xcode